# Search & filter function mutates the state and doesn't return initial state when items have been cleared

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I've implemented a search function which will search and return results from my redux store.
However the result get returned and when I clear the text field the initial state should be return. I end up getting an empty store when I've cleared or entered the wrong keywords.

here is my search & filter function

```
    filter: (state, { payload }) => {
      const itemsToFilter = state.filter((item) => {
        let itemLowerCase = item.item_description.toLowerCase();

        let searchItemToLowerCase = payload.item_description.toLowerCase();

        return itemLowerCase.indexOf(searchItemToLowerCase) > -1;
      });

      if (itemsToFilter) {
        return itemsToFilter;
      }

      return itemInitialState; //initial state of items is not returned
    }
```

and I used `useDispatch` from react-redux

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that in the case where 'you clear the text field' that the result is an event where `payload.item_description` is `''`. In that case, `Array.filter()` won't match anything, but it will still return an empty array (not `null`). So, your check of `itemsToFilter` returns true and your new state is empty. Just check the length of the returned array instead.

```js
filter: (state, { payload }) => {
  const itemsToFilter = state.filter((item) => {
    ...
  });

  if (itemsToFilter.length === 0) {
    return itemsToFilter;
  }

  return itemInitialState;
}
```